# How to inform ExoPlayer's StyledPlayerView about Full Screen State Changes in Android?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to implement the Full-Screen functionality in my Exo Player. For that I used a dialog like shown in the code below:

```
playerView.setFullscreenButtonClickListener {
        if(it){
            this.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
            dialog = object : Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen){
                override fun onBackPressed() {
                    StyledPlayerView.switchTargetView(player, fullScreenPlayerView, playerView)
                    this@MainActivity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
                    
                    // TODO: Inform the Player about the full-screen close event.
                    
                    super.onBackPressed()
                }
            }
            dialog?.addContentView(
                fullScreenPlayerView,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
            )
            dialog?.show()
            StyledPlayerView.switchTargetView(player, playerView, fullScreenPlayerView)
        } else {
            StyledPlayerView.switchTargetView(player, fullScreenPlayerView, playerView)
            this@MainActivity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
            dialog?.dismiss()
        }
    }
```

But I can't find a method that allows us to inform the player that the full screen is closed. I need to inform the player about the full-screen state change when the user presses the back button and we manually switch back to the normal view.

Does anyone know about any such method in the StyledPlayerView?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To those who are looking for an answer and are unwilling to use any custom layout. Here is a solution to the question:

1. You need to set the full-screen image button image manually.
2. You need to check the full-screen status based on dialog visibility.

That's all.

```
playerView.setFullscreenButtonClickListener {

    //  Handle full screen callback based on dialog visibility 
    if(!dialog.isShowing){
        this.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        dialog = object : Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen){
            override fun onBackPressed() {
                StyledPlayerView.switchTargetView(player, fullScreenPlayerView, playerView)
                this@MainActivity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
                
                // You can change the drawable of the image button.
                playerView.findViewById<ImageButton>(com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.R.id.exo_fullscreen)
            .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_expand)
                
                super.onBackPressed()
            }
        }
        dialog?.addContentView(
            fullScreenPlayerView,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
        )
        dialog?.show()
        StyledPlayerView.switchTargetView(player, playerView, fullScreenPlayerView)
    } else {
        StyledPlayerView.switchTargetView(player, fullScreenPlayerView, playerView)
        this@MainActivity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
        dialog?.dismiss()
    }
}
```